# Option converter for XStream in Scala

Tags: scala, xstream

I'm trying to convert objects of type `Option[T]` to XML using Xstream in Scala.  I have a case class like this:

```
case class MyModel(promos: Option[Promos])
```

If the option is `Some(Promo)`, I'd like it to render

```
<MyModel>
  <Promos>
    <promoField1>value</promoField1>
    <promoField2>value</promoField2>
  </Promos>   
</MyModel>
```

If the option is `None`, I'd like it to render

```
<MyModel>
  <Promos/>
</MyModel>
```

So far in my solution, I have registered a converter:

```
xstream.registerConverter(new OptionConverter(xstream.getMapper))
```

I then have a custom converter that looks like this:

```
private [xml] class OptionConverter(_mapper: Mapper) extends AbstractCollectionConverter(_mapper: Mapper) {

  override def marshal(source: scala.Any, writer: HierarchicalStreamWriter, context: MarshallingContext): Unit = {
    val opt = source.asInstanceOf[Option[_]]
    for (value <- opt) {
      writeItem(value, context, writer)
    }
  }

  override def unmarshal(reader: HierarchicalStreamReader, context: UnmarshallingContext): AnyRef = {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException
  }

  override def canConvert(clazz: Class[_]): Boolean = {
    clazz.isAssignableFrom(classOf[Some[_]]) || clazz.isAssignableFrom(None.getClass)
  }
}
```

The `None` works fine, but `Some(promo)` outputs like this:

```
<Promos>
  <com.mymodel.Promos>
    <promoField1>value</promoField1>
    <promoField2>value</promoField2>
  </com.mymodel.Promos>
</Promos>
```

The problem is, Promos is being output for my `Option/Some` field, "com.mymodel.Promos" is then being output for the nested value within `Some`.  Is there a way to flatten is for `Some(value)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make the `Option` Converter to marshal objects to XML.  (The reading part is not required for me, so I left that unimplemented)

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.{MarshallingContext, UnmarshallingContext}
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.{HierarchicalStreamReader, HierarchicalStreamWriter}

private [xml] sealed class OptionConverter extends com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.Converter {

  override def marshal(source: scala.Any, writer: HierarchicalStreamWriter, context: MarshallingContext): Unit = {
    val opt = source.asInstanceOf[Option[_]]
    for (value <- opt) {
      context.convertAnother(opt.get)
    }
  }

  override def unmarshal(reader: HierarchicalStreamReader, context: UnmarshallingContext): AnyRef = {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException
  }

  override def canConvert(clazz: Class[_]): Boolean = {
    clazz.isAssignableFrom(classOf[Some[_]]) || clazz.isAssignableFrom(None.getClass)
  }
}
```

Comment: In the absence of any more answers, I'll mark mine correct - as it seems to work :)